# How do I deserialize a protobuf message at runtime if only class is known in Java?

Tags: java, protobuf-java

I am trying to deserialize a protobuf message in Java, where only a Class object for the corresponding message is given at runtime. I have a solution using reflections, I don't know if this is the best and also the only approach to do so though:

```
byte[] msgData = ...;
Class<? extends Message> msgClass = ...; // this is known
Message msg = (Message) msgClass.getMethod("getDefaultInstanceForType").invoke(msgClass.getConstructor().newInstance());
msg = msg.toBuilder().mergeFrom(msgData).build();
```

Comment: Once you have an instance of Message, you can just call the method `getDefaultInstanceForType` on it: `instance.getDefaultInstanceForType()` - you don't need reflection to call that method.

Comment: Ok you're right using getMethod is not necessary, but to retrieve the Message instance I still need to use reflection right? (`getConstructor().newInstance()`)

Comment: Yes, either call `msgClass.newInstance()` (shorter if you want to invoke the zero-argument constructor) or do what you currently do - in that case you can select from available constructors based on argument types.